# Create a dataclass with field names automatically generated from dict keys

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a `dataclass` from a `dict` not only with the values of the `dict` but also with it's `keys` automatically recognized as field names for the `dataclass`.

The input is

```
d = {'a': 3, 'b': 7}
```

Now I want to do something making like this

```
import dataclasses

# Hocus pocus
X = dataclasses.dataclass_from_dict(name='X', the_dict=d)

print(X)  # <class '__main__.X'> 

z = X(a=3, b=99)                                                                                                         
print(z)  # X(a=3, b=99)
```

The important point here is that the dataclass and it's fields is created **automatically** out of the keys of the dictionary. So there is no need to know the structure and the keys of the dict.

##### What I tried so far

I tried `dataclasses.make_dataclass()` but the result (`AUTO`) is different from a dataclasse created the usual way (`MANUAL`).

```
>>> d = {'a': 3, 'b': 7}
>>> AUTO = dataclasses.make_dataclass('AUTO', [(key, type(d[key])) for key in d])
>>> @dataclass
... class MANUAL:
...   a: int
...   b: int
...
>>> AUTO
<class 'types.AUTO'>
>>> MANUAL
<class '__main__.MANUAL'>
```

Comment: Why? Why not just use a dict?

Comment: A dynamic dataclass seems similar to variable variables -- not very useful.

Comment: With a dict I have to type `d["a"]` but I want to do `d.a`. But I can't use `namedtuples` because I need to manipulate the fields.

Comment: But you can't do `d.a` if the field names are determined dynamically from the dictionary. How would your code know that `a` is a valid field name?

Comment: this is correct, you also lose out on type hinting from an IDE, which is arguably one of the advantage of dataclasses. For example if you do `d.a` on a dynamic generated dataclass, your IDE has **no** idea if it is a `str` or `int` type. It sounds like what you want is a *dotdict* though - dot access for a `dict` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this scenario, the type hinting and auto-complete benefits would largely be missed, so I would personally suggest going with a custom-built `DotDict` approach as outlined below.

I was curious so I timed this against the [`dataclasses.make_dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass) approach. If you are interested, I have also attached my complete test code I used for benchmark purposes.

**Update (6/22):** I’ve come up with a library for this and published on pypi - [`dotwiz`](https://pypi.org/project/dotwiz/). Check it out. It should be just as fast as the approach below, with a few noticeable improvements.

```py
import dataclasses
from timeit import timeit


class DotDict(dict):

    __getattr__ = dict.__getitem__
    __delattr__ = dict.__delitem__

    def __repr__(self):
        fields = [f'{k}={v!r}' for k, v in self.items()]
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({", ".join(fields)})'


def make_dot_dict(input_dict: dict) -> DotDict:
    """
    Helper method to generate and return a `DotDict` (dot-access dict) from a
    Python `dict` object.

    """
    return DotDict(
        (
            k,
            make_dot_dict(v) if isinstance(v, dict)
            else [make_dot_dict(e) if isinstance(e, dict) else e
                  for e in v] if isinstance(v, list)
            else v
        ) for k, v in input_dict.items()
    )


def main():
    d = {'a': 3, 'b': 1, 'c': {'aa': 33, 'bb': [{'x': 77}]}}
    X = dataclasses.make_dataclass('X', d)

    n = 10_000
    globals().update(locals())

    time_to_make_dataclass = timeit("dataclasses.make_dataclass('X', d)", number=n, globals=globals())
    time_to_instantiate_dataclass = timeit("X(**d)", number=n, globals=globals())
    time_to_instantiate_dot_dict = timeit("make_dot_dict(d)", number=n, globals=globals())

    print(f'dataclasses.make_dataclass:     {time_to_make_dataclass:.3f}')
    print(f'instantiate dataclass (X):      {time_to_instantiate_dataclass:.3f}')
    print(f'instantiate dotdict (DotDict):  {time_to_instantiate_dot_dict:.3f}')

    print()

    create_instance_perc = time_to_instantiate_dot_dict / time_to_instantiate_dataclass
    total_time_perc = (time_to_make_dataclass + time_to_instantiate_dataclass) / time_to_instantiate_dot_dict

    print(f'It is {create_instance_perc:.0f}x faster to create a dataclass instance')
    print(f'It is {total_time_perc:.0f}x faster (overall) to create a DotDict instance')

    # create new `DotDict` and check we can use dot-access as well as dict-access

    dd = make_dot_dict(d)

    assert dd.b == 1
    assert dd.c.aa == 33
    assert dd['c']['aa'] == 33
    assert dd.c.bb[0].x == 77

    # create new dataclass `X` instance
    x = X(**d)

    # assert result is same between both DotDict and dataclass approach
    assert dd == x.__dict__


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I received the following results on my Mac (M1 chip):

```
dataclasses.make_dataclass:     1.342
instantiate dataclass (X):      0.002
instantiate dotdict (DotDict):  0.013

It is 6x faster to create a dataclass instance
It is 100x faster (overall) to create a DotDict instance
```

---

As expected, I found the `DotDict` approach to perform overall *much* better in the general case. This is mainly because it doesn't need to dynamically generate a new class, and scan through the `dict` object once to generate the dataclass fields and their types.

Though once the class is initially created, I was surprised to find that the dataclass approach performs about **5x** better in an average case.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`dataclasses.make_dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.make_dataclass) with a dictionary with the appropriate keys.

```
X = dataclasses.make_dataclass('X', d)
```

Then you can instantiate `X` using the same kind of `dict`.

```
z = X(**d)
```

Comment: Please check your code first and tell us your exact Python version. In Python 3.9.10 the `make_dataclass()` does not accept one argument only.

Comment: Oops, I caught that when testing, but forgot to actually fix the answer.

Comment: But why is there the difference I described in the section "What I tried so far" of my question? Does this diff matter?

Comment: I'm not sure why you care about the `repr`.

Comment: It indicates that something is wrong there. Btw pickling is not possible.

Comment: also check out my answer below. this uses a dot dict approach which overall looks like it would be faster :-)